# CHHapticEngine not running

Tags: ios, iphone, hardware, haptic-feedback

After a day of playing with the `CHHapticEngine` and custom haptic patterns, using AHAP files in particular (including adding sound samples), I have lost the sound and haptics in the deivce / iPhone. After a factory reset of the iPhone, there are still no haptics / sound in the device (no ringer, no vibrations etc.). When trying to start the haptics engine and play any pattern I can see the following output in the Xcode debugger:

```
2020-04-29 19:44:31.034051+0200 ProjectName[18431:5043001] [hapi] CHHapticEngine.mm:2354:-[CHHapticEngine doStartWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke: ERROR: Player start failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.CoreHaptics error 1852797029.)
2020-04-29 19:44:31.034398+0200 ProjectName[18431:5042880] [Feedback] failed to start core haptics engine for <_UIFeedbackCoreHapticsEngine: 0x28268f170>: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreHaptics Code=1852797029 "(null)"
2020-04-29 19:44:34.076491+0200 ProjectName[18431:5043124] [hapi] CHHapticEngine.mm:2354:-[CHHapticEngine doStartWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke: ERROR: Player start failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.CoreHaptics error 1852797029.)
2020-04-29 19:44:34.076703+0200 ProjectName[18431:5043124] [hapi] HapticUtils.h:56:_Haptic_Check: -[CHHapticEngine checkEngineState:]: self.running error -4805
2020-04-29 19:44:34.077641+0200 ProjectName[18431:5043124] error = Error Domain=com.apple.CoreHaptics Code=-4805 "(null)" UserInfo={Error =self.running}
```

The question is, is it probable to damage the hardware from code?

Comment: Try running this example and see if the same issue occurs. Maybe something wrong with your code? https://github.com/DanielStormApps/Vibrator

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, I see more or less the same: [hapi] CHHapticEngine.mm:2354:-[CHHapticEngine doStartWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke: ERROR: Player start failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.CoreHaptics error 1852797029.)

Comment: @Daniel, in general my device seems broken physically. I am just surprised this happened when working with haptics. Perhaps a strange coincidence.

Comment: Hmmm perhaps. I can’t find any information on the error code. Reach out to Apple Support.

Comment: i am seeing the same issue after "playing with haptics" on two different devices. Both have now lost their haptic abilities system wide (sound and everything else is ok though). Engine returning -4805 error code on init.

Comment: @Andrei, during last 3 years the "affected" device (an iPhone X) recovered a couple of times. Suddenly, after several months haptics and sound started to work fine. Usually it was for a few hours and then stop, but 99.99% of time it does not work. At the service guys had no idea how to fix the phone.